# Отправка писем из таблиц Google. Как отправить шаблон письма вместе с изображениями

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Вот скрипт рассылки писем из Google Sheets.  Не могу отправить всё письмо по шаблону созданному в Google диске. Получается отправить только часть тела письма, например текст
`text = body.getText();`.

Как отправить всё письмо с изображениями?

```
function mail_template() {      
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1228TXJ5f_dx06XHz-MMSREIdboSKpL_4IbE7ifE");// ID 
  // шаблона письма
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.getId()); // открываем  
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  const text = body.getText(); 
  MailApp.sendEmail('adress@yandex.ru', "Это text body", text);// это работает,
  // а как отправить всё письмо c изображениями?
}
```

Comment: А если так: Это text <img src="url_до_картинки"> body

Comment: Извините. Не понял что такое "url_до_картинки". Возможно вы предлагаете отправить содержимое письма в виде html-кода? Я думаю что есть простой способ отправки письма скриптом из гугл таблиц по его ID в гугл документах.

Comment: К сожалению, другого способа кроме как составить самому html код письма или скопировать код с шаблона ( что не всегда получается корректно с чужих писем) я не нашел. Вот код  function mail() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mailSend'); 
// mailSend -файл html созданный в скрипте таблицы гугл
  var message = htmlOutput.getContent();
  var adress = "adress@yandex.ru";
  MailApp.sendEmail(adress, "Тема",message,{htmlBody : message} ); Хотелось бы иметь простой способ отправки готового письма своего по ID и пересылки чужого.
}